# how to read cookies in jquery?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am creating a cookie with a key and value of an object using carhartl’s jQuery cookie plugin,In one of my method I call create cookie and right after that I call get cookie;but the read method doesn't work:
makeCookie methode:

```
function makeCookie(name,value){
    $.cookie(name,value);
}
```

readCookie method:

```
function readCookie(name){
    $.parseJSON($.cookie(name));
}
```

and calling these 2 methods:

```
makeCookie('chatPopups',popUps);
    var all=readCookie('chatPopups');
    alert(all);
```

popUps is a global javascript object;

The error I get is :

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: please console.log($.cookie(name)) in readCookie function and list its log here. so it will help to answer

Comment: it logs [object Object], and i can't get objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem,changed makeCookie method to this:

```
function makeCookie(name,value){
    $.cookie(name,$.param(value),{ path: '/' });
}
```

and readCookie method to this:

```
function readCookie(name){
    var readCookie=$.cookie(name);
    readCookie = readCookie.split('&');
    if(readCookie.length != 0){
    for (i=0; i<readCookie.length; i++) {
        readCookie[i] = readCookie[i].split('=');
        popUps[readCookie[i][0]] = readCookie[i][1];
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code change in `readCookie` function

**readCookie method:**

```
function readCookie(name){
    return $.cookie(name); // no parse needed because its not a json object of cookie
}
```

Comment: it returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your $.cookie() methods look fine.

The problem most probably lies in popUps, which might not be a well-formed JSON string as $.parseJSON() is very sensitive.

Since popUps is a global JavaScript object, you could just `return $.cookie(name);` without JSON parseing.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this

```
function getCookieValue(cname) { // cname is nothing but the cookie value which contains 
                            // the value
                    var name = cname + "=";
                      var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
                      var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
                      for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
                        var c = ca[i];
                        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                          c = c.substring(1);
                        }
                        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                          return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                        }
                      }
                      return "";
                    }
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer and not just code.